# Ruby array.each and RestClient skipping array elements

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I've a array of elements and for each element, I've to make a get call using RestClient. However, I see a few of the array elements are being skipped.

```rb
    total_hosts = []
    puts "total_hosts initially = " + total_hosts.size.to_s
    require 'rest-client'
    total_hosts = %w{10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3 10.0.0.4 10.0.0.5 10.0.0.6 10.0.0.7 10.0.0.8 10.0.0.9 10.0.0.10 10.0.0.11 10.0.0.12 10.0.0.13 10.0.0.14 10.0.0.15}
    puts "total_hosts after adding = " + total_hosts.size.to_s
    total_hosts.each { |host|
        begin
        sleep 1
        RestClient.get("http://#{host}/get_my_build") { |response|
            case response.code
            when 200
                if response.body.include?("Your build number is 10")
                    puts "Latest build on #{host}"
                else
                    puts "Older build on #{host}"
                end
            when 404
                puts "Exception on #{host} not reachable"
            end
        }
        rescue => e
        puts "Exception on #{host}"
    end
    }
    puts "job completed"
```

**Output :**

---

```
Latest build on 10.0.0.3
Latest build on 10.0.0.4
Exception on 10.0.0.5
Latest build on 10.0.0.6
Latest build on 10.0.0.7
Latest build on 10.0.0.8
Latest build on 10.0.0.9
Exception on 10.0.0.10
Latest build on 10.0.0.11
Latest build on 10.0.0.12
Latest build on 10.0.0.13
Latest build on 10.0.0.14
Latest build on 10.0.0.15
```

I could see hosts 1 and 2 are missing in the output. If I run the same script after some time they might be listed in the output but some other hosts are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your script encounters an HTTP Response that is not 200 or 404, your script does nothing. So, if a host has a temporary error, or a redirection, or tells you to try again, or simply gives you some information, or any of the other ~60 possible responses, you simply ignore that host completely.